# Protractor: how to wait for multiple options to be visible

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, protractor

I'm using Protractor and I have a situation where I have html game and in the game three options that are available based on the play:

- option 1
- option 2
- option 3

So how should I write if clause to check whether option 1 is displayed or option 2 or option 3, so that I can make further interactions based on displayed option?

Currently I have the following written for option 1:

```
// wait for option 1 pop up not to be visible
browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(game.option1PopUp), 60000).then(function(isNotVisible) {

    //if (isNotPresent) {
    if (isNotVisible) {

        // verify element is not visible
        isNotVisible == true;
        console.log("\tNo option 1 is displayed.\n");

    } else {

        // verify element is visible
        isNotVisible == false;
        console.log("\tOption 1 is displayed.\n");

        // wait for button to be clickable
        browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(game.option1OkButton), 15000).then(function() {

        // click on button
        game.option1OkButton.click();

    };

});
```

How can I check if option 1 is not displayed, but option 2 is or perhaps option 3? Only one option can be displayed at once.

Comment: could you pass DOM structure?

Comment: Afraid I cannot, but in the DOM it's simple and straightforward. All options are already present, but get active state once they are displayed. What I need is logic on how to check which option is displayed and then perform specific step, based on that option.